# htaccess multiple query string not working

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

**I want to get this URL:**

example.com/scooter-details/1/vespa-sprint

**But the URL I get is:**

example.com/scooter-details.php?scooter_id=1&scooter_brand=vespasprint&scooter_model=

The scooter_model "sprint" is in the `scooter_brand` query, Normally it has to be `scooter_brand=vespa&scooter_model=sprint`. Hope you can help me with this

#### Here is the `htaccess` code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
# SEO FRIENDLY URL

# Redirect "/scooter-details.php?service_id=<num>" to "/scooter-details/<num>"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^scooter_id=(\d+)&scooter_brand=([^/.]+)&scooter_model=([^/.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(scooter-details)\.php$ /$1/%1/$2%2-$3%3? [QSD,L,R=301,N]

# Rewrite "/scooter-details/<num>" back to "scooter-details.php?service_id=<num>"
RewriteRule ^(scooter-details)/(\d+)/([^/]+)$ $1.php?scooter_id=$2&scooter_brand=$3&scooter_model=$4 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You most probably need the `NE` (`noescape`) flag on the `RewriteRule` directive if you are capturing elements of the query string (which is already URL-encoded) and using these to build the URL-path. Otherwise you will end up doubly-URL-encoding parts of the resulting URL-path - which is what this looks like.

`%2520` is a doubly URL-encoded *space*. ie. you would seem to have `%20` (ie. a *space*) in the query string you are capturing from.

However, the rule you have posted does not seem to relate to the example URLs given?

Comment: Sorry I didn't saw it. I changed the question for you. Hope this will help you.